# Какие задачи решает структура ArraySegment<T>?

Tags: c#, .net

Какие задачи решает структура ArraySegment?

С виду, похоже, что копирует кусок массива в эту структуру и позволяет ее изменять отдельно от основного массива и не портя исходного массива.

Разве не тоже самое можно получить созданием List ?

Comment: Создав `List`, данные в него придётся _копировать_, а это затратно. При передаче куда-либо `ArraySegment`, данные не копируются, передаётся лишь ссылка.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, т.е это обертка над массивом, цель которой исключить копирование массива при передачи в метод? Хорошо, а что мешает с самого начала завести List нужного типа? Вроде, массивы не сильно пользуются популярностью. Или это больше для поддержки старого кода?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4600827/276994

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда требуется работать не со всем массивом данных, а лишь с его частью, нужно передать в метод три параметра: ссылку на сам массив, индекс начала, количество элементов.

```
void Foo(int[] array, int startIndex, int count)
```

Если при этом нужны и другие параметры, то сигнатура метода становится длинной и малопонятной:

```
void Foo(int[] array, int startIndex, int count, SomeTypeA param1, SomeTypeB param2)
```

Есть распространённый способ рефакторинга: замена параметров объектом (структурой). Я так понимаю, что `ArraySegment` как раз и является таким объектом, заранее введённым разработчиками фреймворка.

```
void Foo(ArraySegment<int> segment)

void Foo(ArraySegment<int> segment, SomeTypeA param1, SomeTypeB param2)
```

Такая сигнатура несколько проще.

Конечно, можно и для других параметров ввести свой объект (но его нужно предварительно написать самим):

```
void Foo(ArraySegment<int> segment, SomeObject obj)
```

---

То, что массивы ныне совсем мало используются по сравнению с другими коллекциями, совсем другой вопрос.

Answer (score -3):

[Тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1hsbd92d(v=vs.110).aspx) смотреть не пробовали?

Структура ArraySegment - Определяет границы фрагмента одномерного массива. И методы описаны и весь букет.

Вот простой пример использования:

```
var array = new byte[] { 5, 8, 9, 20, 70, 44, 2, 4 };
array.Dump();
var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(array, 2, 3);
segment.Dump(); // output: 9, 20, 70
segment.Reverse().Dump(); // output 70, 20, 9
segment.Any(s => s == 99).Dump(); // output false
segment.First().Dump(); // output 9
array.Dump(); // no change
```

Comment: Вопрос же не в том, какие методы есть у этого класса. Топикастер хочет знать - зачем вообще этот класс нужен.